# Use DataContext as CommandParameter in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I want to pass the current DataContext (which is an instance of a ViewModel) as a CommandParameter on a WPF Button.  What would be the syntax I should use?

```
<Button 
  x:Name="btnMain"
  Command="infra:ApplicationCommands.MyCommand"
  CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"
 />
```

Comment: Notice that the order matters here. `CommandParameter` must come before `Command` or else you'll see only `null` being passed as a parameter.

Comment: Nope, I just tested it; the order does not matter!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

An empty Binding, without a path, binds directly to the DataContext, so

```
{Binding}
```

is enough to make it work! Your example:

```
<Button 
  x:Name="btnMain"
  Command="infra:ApplicationCommands.MyCommand"
  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
 />
```

Comment: This is so simple it is brilliant.  Nice :)

Answer (score 13):

```
<Button 
   x:Name="btnMain"
   Command="infra:ApplicationCommands.MyCommand"
   CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
/>
```

as long as the button is within the Visual tree of the item with the DataContext